# Combining object data type rows and columns without loosing data

Tags: python, pandas, schema, aggregate, reformatting

i've been tasked with cleaning data from a mobile application designed by a charity

In one section, a users Q/A app use session is represented by a row. This section consists of repeated question answer field pairs, where a field represents the question asked and then the field next to it represents the corresponding answer. Together, each question/field and answer column pair represent a unique question with the answer.

Starting data

```
 answers.0.answer    answers.0.fieldName answers.1.answer    answers.1.fieldName
5   0                    avoidexercise             0.0            vomitflag
6   156                  height                    54.0         weight
7   1                    affectedkneeside           3.0       painlocationknee
```

The ideal output

I have been asked to reformat the section so each question forms a column, the corresponding answer a field in that column

The ideal output

```
_id                    avoidexercise    enjoyment   fatigue2weeks   height
        

5f27f29c362a380d3f9a9e46    1.0           yes            20.0       120.0
5f27f2ac362a380d3f9a9e4b    0.0           no             40.0       180.0
5f27f4d4362a380d3f9a9e52    1.0           yes            50.0       150.0
```

enter image description here

My plan is to create many pivot tables, from each other Q/A pairs of columns, then concaternate (outer join) then inner join to remove duplications

However, the original dataframe contains a mixture of numeric and object datatypes

Therefore, only some question/answer column pairs appear to be converting to pivot tables. I have tried using various aggregate functions

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p2 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.1.fieldName'],values=['answers.1.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
p3 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.2.fieldName'],values=['answers.2.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x))
I have also tried another lambda function

p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns= ['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'],aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x)
```

The furthest I have got so far is to run pivots with standard mean aggfunc

```
p1 = ur.pivot_table(index=['_id'],columns=['answers.0.fieldName'],values=['answers.0.answer'])
ps = [p1,p2,p3]
c = pd.concat(ps)
```

Then attempting to remove merge rows and columns

```
df = c.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)

g = df.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
This returns a dataframe with the right shape
```

However, it looses the values in the object columns, and I'm not sure how accurate all the numeric columns are

To overcome this problem, I was considering converting as much data as I can into numeric

```
c4 = c.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').info()
```

Then splitting the combined pivot table dataframe into numeric and object type

```
nu = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
cndf = c4.select_dtypes(include=nu)
o = ['object', 'bool', 'datetime64', 'category']
codf = c4.select_dtypes(include=o)
```

And running through the same .sum and groupby operations as above on the numeric dataframe

```
n1 = cndf.sum(axis=1, level=1, skipna=False)
n2 = n1.groupby('_id').agg(np.sum)
```

However, this still leaves the challenge of dealing with the object columns

Comment: Is your starting data actually a DF in that format - or some JSON data? If the later - it almost looks like if you loaded that data different in the first place - you wouldn't end up processing it once it's in a DF.

Comment: Interesting question, think you could be on to something

It came from a mobile application, and was given to me as an excel document

Would it be worth looking at how the data comes out of the app